# __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents' discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

I was trying to make a discord bot and I used this code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@bot.event

async def on_ready():
print("Black_knight is up again")\`
```

and this error pops up:

```
line 6, in \<module\>
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

Also, I tried putting

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
```

before `bot.commands`, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work but IT IMPORTS ALL INTENTS

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)
```

Comment: No problem, I hope your discord bot won't have any more problems in the future!